# Find org where connected app was created to update its config params (having only consumerKey and consumerSecret)

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

At some point in the past (many years ago) we created connected app in one of our SF orgs.
Since then we've been actively using consumerKey and consumerSecret provided by that connected app when authenticating users into different SF orgs via oauth2 flow from our custom ios mobile app.

And now we need to update some config params of this connected app.
The funny thing is that no one remember which org that connected app was created into (and if that org is still around at all).

Is there any way just by having consumerKey and consumerSecret detect org id where connected app was created?
I.e. we can log in to different SF orgs by using this consumerKey/consumerSecret and with appropriate username/password, but we are not interested here in id of user's org, we need to know id of the org which hosts this connected app (to log in there and update some params).

Any help or ideas whould be appreciated - have no clue where even to start from.

Comment: Does the app come from a managed package? What parameters are you changing?

Comment: @HaroutTatarian No, app is not from managed package - it was created right in the org.

Comment: There's no way to know the hosting/originating org from consumer key (secret doesn't matter) and that is intentional. You have to go org by org - you can hit the org via oAuth and use the org-specific URL (not `test.s.c` or `login.s.c.`) or use Metadata API

Comment: I’m curious to know how a connected app host on org X is being used to auth into other orgs? Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: @identigral what if that org has already been decomissioned by SF due to inactivity? and I am not 100% sure that it was a dev org, it could have been a sandbox, which was already refreshed couple times afterwards. We've already went through all known dev orgs, prod orgs and even sandboxes (up to 500 orgs), but still no success to find a match.

Comment: Decommissioned or refreshed (and no longer containing the original app) org are interesting use cases. Opening a case with SF support might be your only option here. Longer-term solution: use a well-known production org as your connected app host and modify your mobile app to point there.

Answer (score 0):

Log a case with Salesforce. They will be able to tell which app the credentials were generated from.